# Strtotime - возможны ли мультивычисления даты?

Tags: php

Очень удобная функция **strtotime**
Пример:
`$newdate = strtotime('-3 week', strtotime($date));`
Недавно возникло желание помучить её.
Хочу узнать, возможно ли реализовать что-то подобное?
Пример:
`$newdate = strtotime('-3 day', '-3 week', '-3 month', '-3 year', strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из официальной документации `echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";`